# Android SIP profile locked after reinstall

Tags: android, voip, sip

I'm using the SIP stack in Android 2.3.x+ (actually testing on Motorola Xoom though) and have successfully got a softphone working.  However, I uninstalled the app (without unregistering the SIP profile, so it is still registered).  Upon reinstalling the app, when using the same profile details (which is a requirement - don't want to change phone numbers/domains every time I uninstall), android says:

```
only creator or radio can query on the profile
```

So I can never use that profile again, as I can never become the creator as I uninstalled the app!

This seems like a huge flaw - the user would have to know that he must logout of the service before uninstalling, and if he doesn't, the app becomes useless!

Am I missing something obvious?  Can I get access to this profile, or delete it, in a user-friendly way?

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: Make sure you signed with same certificate both the version of app you installed first time, and second time.

Comment: I don't think it's that - I'm still just running from eclipse - so not signed by anything (or if it signs behind the scenes, I assume it's the same certificate).

Comment: Sorry - turns out that a restart of the device has fixed the problem.  Strangely it now isn't repeatable, so I guess the Xoom got into a strange state somehow...  Can't self-answer for another 8 hours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting device fixed the problem.